# Split a 2D array into single arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am bit new in JQuery ,,I have a 2D Array

```
2DArray =[2.0,6.31]
         [3.0,6.09]
         [4.0,7.44]
```

I want to split it into 2 One dimensional Array like this:

```
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0]    
[6.31, 6.09, 7.44]
```

I have read posts about convert single array into multidimensional array but not vice versa ...

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: How do you expect to get at all the elements of the original array if you don't loop through them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should about do it, *you have to loop*:

```
var twoDArray =[[2.0,6.31],
         [3.0,6.09],
         [4.0,7.44]];

var xArray = [];
var yArray = [];

$.each(twoDArray, function(index, value) {
    xArray.push(value[0]);
    yArray.push(value[1]);
});
```

BTW 2DArray is an invalid variable name. You can't use 2 at the start of a variable.

Also your array declaration is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the JavsScript [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
var twoDArray =[[2.0,6.31],
               [3.0,6.09],
               [4.0,7.44]];

var xArray = twoDArray.map(function(tuple) {
    return tuple[0];
});
var yArray = twoDArray.map(function(tuple) {
    return tuple[1];
});
```

Comment: Or more simply: `twoDArray.map(tuple => tuple[1])`

Answer (score -1):

Create 2 arrays for each row put first column in first array and second on in the second array. This link would give you all the array operation you have in jQuery.

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/

Alternately you can even use a for loop with index.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.