# select cells in a column WHERE corresponding cells' value is given

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

suppose you have a spreadsheet like this in Google Sheets

[image]
and you want to 
SUM all the values of the cells in Q:Q **WHERE the CORRESPONDING cell** (i.e. *on the same row*) in column D:D has certain given values ..

Now, if we were in some DB language like MySql I suppose this would be quite easy and you would probably instruct something like

```sql
SELECT cells in "Tot. / Anno" (Q:Q) WHERE "level" (D:D) is B or MID
```

and that would be it, but I guess nothing so direct is possible in Javascript; so I am afraid a little workaround is needed.

**So, first of all, what's the logic behind the sheet?**
In column D:D under **level** you have four options which you can select from, and these are: *b*, *mid*, *pro* and *top*. B stands for basic, and the logic here is trying to build a **gradual budget**.
Some kind of expenses are basical and you can't avoid them, like medical or your bank account or telephone; while others like leisure and travels are secondary and you can spare on them; so they are not fundamental, but most likely *mid* *pro* or even *top* :)
This is the logic behind and the scale of values.

When you select a given criterium in D2 you should get the matching SUM in G2 based on the same **gradual** logic:

```py
b   in D2  -->  only sum cells in Q:Q where value is b
mid in D2  -->  only sum cells in Q:Q where value is b OR mid
pro in D2  -->  only sum cells in Q:Q where value is b OR mid OR pro
top in D2  -->       sum cells in Q:Q where value is b OR mid OR pro OR top
```

Now, as to coding, this is the workaround that I've found. **It does work**, but it's not elegant.
I would like to hear some more efficient and proper way to deal with the matter: I am at a elementary level and I am sure a more effecient solution is available

```js
// onEdit is meant to make sure that a real-time recalculation is triggered  
// at any change within the specified columns
function onEdit(e){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var cell = sheet.getRange("Q2");
  var range = e.range;
  var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();

  if (columnOfCellEdited === 4 || 17) {


// creating 2 different arrays from the two different comlumns (ranges)  
var range1 = sheet.getRange("D3:D100").getValues();
var range2 = sheet.getRange("Q3:Q100").getValues();  

// merging the two single arrays into one 2d array (you can't have one single 
// 2d array from the start because the two columns are not adjacent I guess)
var range=[],i=-1;
while ( range1[++i] ) { 
  range.push( [ range1[i][0], range2[i][0] ] );
}

// I tried to come up with a global SUM but I don't know why it does not work
// var valore_glob = range2.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }, 0);

// as much filters as given values in the validation drop-down list: each  
// filter returns only the correspoding values

// FILTRO BASE - keeps only B values
var filt_bas = range.filter(function (dataRow) {  return dataRow[0] ===  'b';});
// splitting the 2d array into two singles arrays, we keep only the second  
// one for the follwing SUM
var yArray_bas = filt_bas.map(function(tuple) {    return tuple[1];});  
// summing up all the values within the resulting array
var valore_bas = yArray_bas.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }, 0);

// FILTRO MID - keeps only MID values 
var filt_mid = range.filter(function (dataRow) {  return dataRow[0] ===  'mid';});
// splitting the 2d array into two singles arrays, we keep only the second  
// one for the follwing SUM
var yArray_mid = filt_mid.map(function(tuple) {    return tuple[1];});  
// summing up all the values within the resulting array
var valore_mid = yArray_mid.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }, 0);

// FILTRO PRO - keeps only PRO  values  
var filt_pro = range.filter(function (dataRow) {  return dataRow[0] ===  'pro';});
// splitting the 2d array into two singles arrays, we keep only the second  
// one for the follwing SUM
var yArray_pro = filt_pro.map(function(tuple) {    return tuple[1];});  
// summing up all the values within the resulting array
var valore_pro = yArray_pro.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }, 0);  

// FILTRO TOP - keeps only TOP values 
var filt_top = range.filter(function (dataRow) {  return dataRow[0] ===  'top';});
// splitting the 2d array into two singles arrays, we keep only the second  
// one for the follwing SUM
var yArray_top = filt_top.map(function(tuple) {    return tuple[1];});  
// summing up all the values within the resulting array
var valore_top = yArray_top.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }, 0);   

var selector = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();

switch (selector) {
  default:
    cell.setValue(valore_bas);
    break;
  case 'mid':
    cell.setValue(valore_bas + valore_mid);
    break;
  case 'pro':
    cell.setValue(valore_bas + valore_mid + valore_pro);
    break;
  case 'top':
    cell.setValue(valore_bas + valore_mid + valore_pro + valore_top);
}

  }
}
```

suggestions are welcome, thanks.

credits:
[Writing google Javascript similar to vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838294/writing-google-javascript-similar-to-vlookup)
[Sum elements of an array with specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532596/sum-elements-of-an-array-with-specific-attribute)
[Spreadsheet Non-Adjacent Column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234752/spreadsheet-non-adjacent-column-data)
[How to find the sum of an array of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230233/how-to-find-the-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers)
[How to filter an array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849369/how-to-filter-an-array-of-arrays)
[Split a 2D array into single arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614791/split-a-2d-array-into-single-arrays)

latest working actual code as in code.gs:
https://jsfiddle.net/John_Galassi/5ahrLmg9/

Comment: If this was Excel I'd be looking at a simple SUMIFS function, but I have no idea about Google Sheets

Comment: To clean it up a little, I suggest you to use arrow functions to make this (and other examples) `var filt_bas = range.filter(function (dataRow) {  return dataRow[0] ===  'b';});` to this `var filt_bas = range.filter((dataRow) => dataRow[0] ===  'b');` a bit easier on the eyes if you ask me.

Comment: I agree with @HarassedDad, the [sumif](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) function should be sufficient?

Comment: @MauriceNino I did try it in the beginning, but it seemed to me this notation wasn't working on GAS, can you confirm? I'll try that again anyway, thanks

Comment: @HarassedDad, Casper yes that could work in excel, but my wish would be to implement something from the code side. thanks for your answers though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using built-in functions you could try

```
=iferror(sumproduct(regexmatch(D3:D, "^("&vlookup(D2, {"b", "b"; "mid", "b|mid"; "pro", "b|mid|pro"; "top", "b|mid|pro|top"}, 2, 0)&")$"), Q3:Q))
```

or, depending on your locale

```
=iferror(sumproduct(regexmatch(D3:D; "^("&vlookup(D2; {"b"\ "b"; "mid"\ "b|mid"; "pro"\"b|mid|pro"; "top"\ "b|mid|pro|top"}; 2; 0)&")$"); Q3:Q))
```

Or, you can create a custom function in google script:

```
function sumOnCondition(filter, checkrange, sumrange) {
var arr, ind;
arr = ["b", "mid", "pro", "top"];
ind = arr.indexOf(filter);
arr = (filter === "top") ? arr : arr.slice(0, ind + 1);
return checkrange.map(function(r, i) {
    return arr.indexOf(r[0]) > -1 ? Number(sumrange[i]) : 0;
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
})
}
```

and in the spreadsheet enter in G2

```
=sumOnCondition(D2, D3:D, Q3:Q)
```

or, depending on your locale

```
=sumOnCondition(D2; D3:D; Q3:Q)
```

See if that helps?

Comment: I get an error in both case.
I get "TypeError: Impossibile chiamare il metodo "map" di undefined. (riga 6, file "sum")"

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet so I can take a closer look?

Comment: yes of course thanks, let me prepare it and I'll post a link at the end of my original question. thanks

Comment: Hi again, your locale requires the use of semi-colons as argument separators. I've updated both formulas and entered them in your spreadsheet (cells T2 and U2). See if it now works?

Comment: thanks man, it seems to work. there's still a couple of questions I would like to pose but it seems to work for now. Really many thanks, it's really slim and more elegant than my previous one. I hope I can ask you on additional questions later on. thanks

Comment: Most welcome, @JohnGalassi. Feel free to start a new thread whenever you need help.